# Using environment variables in the Folder Description with Cloudbees Jenkins Folders Plugin

Tags: jenkins, directory, cloudbees

I want my Folder Description to display the value of an environment variable set in the folder configuration.  I did try using the normal syntax, e.g. %JOB_NAME% in the description field.  The description displays the exact text %JOB_NAME% rather than the value of the variable.

Is this not supported for the Folder/

thanks

Glenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the description should be literal text. Folder variables may be accessed during *builds*, using `$VARNAME` or `${VARNAME}` syntax.